# Swift UITabbar Shadow in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I try to apply shadow to default tabbar. I find some code from research but it doesnt work. I want to put this code in AppDelegate for applying to all controllers.

Where is the mistake ? Thanks in advance

```
UITabBar.appearance().layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
UITabBar.appearance().layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
UITabBar.appearance().layer.shadowRadius = 15
UITabBar.appearance().layer.shadowOpacity = 1
UITabBar.appearance().layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

Step 1 - Create a function setupTabBar in TabBarViewController like this

```
func setupTabBar() {
        tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 15
        tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false

    }
```

Step 2 - Call from viewDidLoad

Or else you can create Custom TabBarViewController class or create it how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Create Image of Your Shadow Color from AnyTool or you can do it programatically.

After That use Below code in AppDelegate

```
//Set Shadow Color
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = YOURSHADOWIMAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

try self.tabBar.layer instead of UITabBar.appearance()